# PDFbox This font type only supports 8-bit code points

Tags: android, pdfbox

i am having some problems with this library, please help me, i've tried with roboto and arial ttf and it doesn't working, i am trying to write Sigma Σ symbol in PDF and it ends with an exeption, i need to know if i need to encode this, and how can i do it, thanks in advance

```
public void drawTable(PDPage page, PDPageContentStream contentStream,
                      float y, float margin,
                      String[][] content) throws IOException {
    final int rows = content.length;
    final int cols = content[0].length;
    final float rowHeight = 20f;
    final float tableWidth = page.getBBox().getWidth()-(2*margin);
    final float tableHeight = rowHeight * rows;
    final float colWidth = tableWidth/(float)cols;
    final float cellMargin=5f;

    //draw the rows
    float nexty = y ;
    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
        contentStream.drawLine(margin,nexty,margin+tableWidth,nexty);
        nexty-= rowHeight;
    }

    //draw the columns
    float nextx = margin;
    for (int i = 0; i <= cols; i++) {
        contentStream.drawLine(nextx,y,nextx,y-tableHeight);
        nextx += colWidth;
    }


    //now add the text
    contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.COURIER,12);
    PDTrueTypeFont robotoRegular = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(document, getActivity().getAssets().open("arial.ttf"));
    robotoRegular.encode("WinAnsiEncoding");
    PDTrueTypeFont robotBold = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(document, getActivity().getAssets().open("ariblk.ttf"));
    robotBold.encode("WinAnsiEncoding");
    float textx = margin+cellMargin;
    float texty = y-15;
    for(int i = 0; i < content.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < content[i].length; j++){
            String text = content[i][j];
            contentStream.beginText();
            if (j==0){
                contentStream.setFont(robotBold,12);
            }else {
                contentStream.setFont(robotoRegular,12);
            }
//                byte[] commands = "Σ".getBytes();
//                commands[1] = (byte) 128;
//                contentStream.appendRawCommands(commands);
            contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(textx,texty);
            contentStream.drawString(text);
            contentStream.endText();
            textx += colWidth;
        }
        texty-=rowHeight;
        textx = margin+cellMargin;
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt this will work with PDFBox for android, which is based on PDFBox 1.8. You could try using the PDType1Font.SYMBOL, and encode yourself, the octal code for sigma is hex 53 (see pdf specification Annex A). I.e. use that, Tj and \n as your raw command. The `robotoRegular.encode("WinAnsiEncoding");` lines are irrelevant, you don't need them. Alternatively, create your PDF on the server and use 2.* version.

Comment: Seems that PDFBox for android is using some 2.0 concepts. See https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android/issues/100 at the bottom. If it works, please answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested, and using LiberationSans as your font will allow you to encode the sigma symbol.

`PDFont liberationSans = PDType0Font.load(document, getActivity().getAssets().open("com/tom_roush/pdfbox/resources/ttf/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf"));` will load the font, then you can drawString as usual.